# Twitter Bootstrap datepicker Formatting Issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui-datepicker, datepicker

I am using twitter boostrap datepicker in mvc4 application. In my Model, I am setting date property as-

```
 [DisplayName("Date Last Modified")]
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}")]
 public DateTime? EmpLastModified { get; set; }
```

Jquery datepicker is as-

```
@if (Model.HasValue && ((DateTime)Model.Value).Year > 1500)
{
   @Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:dd/MMM/yyyy }", Model.Value), new { @class =      "textbox", @style = "width:125px;" })
}
else {
@Html.TextBox("", String.Format("{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}", DateTime.Now), new { @class =   "textbox", @style = "width:125px;" })
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#@id").datepicker
        ({
            dateFormat: '0:dd/MMM/yyyy',
            showStatus: true,
            showWeeks: true,
            highlightWeek: true,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            showAnim: "scale",
            showOptions: {
                origin: ["top", "left"]
            }
        });
    });
```

The date picker should display 23-May-2013 as date, but it displays 11/23/2013 whereas in firebug it shows

```
<input id="EmpDateAdded" class="textbox" type="text" value="23-May-2013" style="width:125px;" name="EmpDateAdded" data-val-date="The field Date Added To System must be a date." data-val="true">
```

I an using datepicker.css and bootstrap-datepicker.js, date.format.js

Please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format string for the datepicker is not the same as .NET.  Assuming you're using the [eternicode version](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker), use this as format guidelines for the datepicker (lifted from the Docs):

```
Default: 'mm/dd/yyyy'

The date format, combination of d, dd, D, DD, m, mm, M, MM, yy, yyyy.

d, dd: Numeric date, no leading zero and leading zero, respectively. Eg, 5, 05.
D, DD: Abbreviated and full weekday names, respectively. Eg, Mon, Monday.
m, mm: Numeric month, no leading zero and leading zero, respectively. Eg, 7, 07.
M, MM: Abbreviated and full month names, respectively. Eg, Jan, January
yy, yyyy: 2- and 4-digit years, respectively. Eg, 12, 2012.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot....It got the point....I needed to change the date format in bootstrap-datepicker.js

Answer (score 0):

I would recommended you to use moment.js
If you are able to used any library in your work.